# Install Flask on Shared Web Host

Tags: python, flask

I can run "./flaskcgi.cgi" but I cannot make it work on the browser (domain.com/testing/). I only get a 500 internal server error. The two python files are "+x"'d with chmod.

flaskapp.py (in /scgi-bin/.):

```
#!/home/NAME/public_html/cgi-bin/flask/bin/python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/testing'

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

flaskcgi.cgi (in /scgi-bin/.):

```
#!/home/NAME/public_html/cgi-bin/flask/bin/python

import os, sys
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler

os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = '127.0.0.1'
os.environ['SERVER_PORT'] = '5000'
os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'
os.environ['PATH_INFO'] = ""

log = open('log.txt', 'a')
log.write("____\n")
log.flush()

app = None
try:
    from flaskapp import app
    CGIHandler().run(app)
except Exception, e:
    log.write(str(e) + "\n")
```

.htaccess (in /testing/.):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/NAME/public_html/scgi-bin/flaskcgi.cgi/$1 [L]
```

**Update 1** - I'm able to finally execute /testing but I cannot get the correct request path.

New www/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^testing/(.*)$ /home/NAME/public_html/scgi-bin/flaskcgi.cgi/$1 [L]
```

However when I go to https://domain.com/testing/about?a=1, I get:

```
request.path: /
request.url: https://domain.com/scgi-bin/flaskcgi.cgi/?a=1
request.script_root: /scgi-bin/flaskcgi.cgi.
```

I am expecting /about?a=1 as request.path.

Comment: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)` and see if the info there will give you more info.

Comment: Since I'm importing flaskapp.py, the __main__ code is never called.